# Flutter ListView can't tap items

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter_maps map and overlaying a custom search bar with drop down menu. When user searches, locations appear and should be clickable. Using the below code, the UI appears, but clicks aren't possible and nothing happens. I've also noticed the list view can't be scrolled either, can anyone see what the issue is?

```
List<Widget> _locations = [];


Future<void> searchLocations(String input) async {
    final database =
        await $FloorLocalDatabase.databaseBuilder('local_database.db').build();

    final locationsDao = database.locationDao;

    locationsDao.searchLocations(input).then((value) => {
          setState(() {
            _locations = [];
            value.forEach((element) {
              _locations.add(locationItem(element));
            });
          })
        });
  }



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlutterMap(
        options: MapOptions(
          center: LatLng(51.5072, -0.1276),
          zoom: zoom,
          interactiveFlags: InteractiveFlag.pinchZoom | InteractiveFlag.drag,
        ),
        children: [
          TileLayer(
              urlTemplate: "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"),
          MarkerLayer(markers: _markers),
          Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 56.0,
                child: Card(
                  shape: roundedCorner32,
                  elevation: 6.0,
                  child: Wrap(children: [
                    Column(children: [
                      TextField(
                        cursorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                  width: 0,
                                  style: BorderStyle.none,
                                )),
                            filled: true,
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                            hintText: search,
                            fillColor: Colors.white),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          searchLocations(value);
                        },
                      ),
                      if (_locations.isNotEmpty) ...[
                        Card(
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                          shape: roundedCorner16,
                          elevation: 6.0,
                          child: Wrap(children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                                child: ListView.separated(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemCount: _locations.length,
                                    itemBuilder:
                                        (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                      return GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          print("XXXXXXXXXXX");
                                        },
                                        child: _locations[index],
                                      );
                                    }, separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                      return const SizedBox(height: 8.0);
                                },),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                        )
                      ]
                    ]),
                  ]),
                ),
              )),
        ]);
  }

  Widget locationItem(Location location) {
    return AutoSizeText(buildFullLocation(location), maxLines: 1);
  }
```

Comment: do you have this issue in flutter web?

Comment: Can you include more about `_locations`

Comment: you can try with `onPanDown` instead of `onTap`

Comment: Can you produce minimal reproducible  code. so that i can check in my machine aswell and help you out

Comment: @YeasinSheikh onPanDown doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya what other code do you need?

Comment: I see the code involves backend unfortunately. You cannot produce reproducible code for me to test

Comment: can you provide a simplified, minimal widget that will reproduce the same error

Answer (score 0):

How about try wrap the TextFiled widget in an Inkwell or GestureDetector widget?

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){},
            child: TextField()),
```